# Question about orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. I am trying to show that every self-adjoint idempotent continuous linear transformation is the orthogonal projection onto some closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. If $P$ is such an operator, the obvious thing is to consider $S=\{Px:x\in\mathcal{H}\}$. However, I'm having trouble showing that S is in fact closed even though I'm sure this should be almost trivial. I tried to show that if $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\in S$ then $x\in S$ but somehow I just can't quite do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient way to check for closure of subspaces is to try to write the subspace as the kernel of some continuous operator.

Note that $(I-P)x = 0$ **iff** $Px=x$.

Note that $x \in S$ **iff** $x = Py$ for some $y$ **iff** $Px = x$, and so
$S = \ker (I-P)$. Hence $S$ is closed.

Comment: Ahh! That is a trick that I was not aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: use continuity of $P$. Then show what the kernel of $P$ is orthogonal to $S$.

Comment: Here's what I have: if $x_n\in S$ then $x_n=Py_n$ for some $y_n$. If I can show that $y_n\to y$ for some $y$ then by the continuity of $P$ it follows that $Py_n\to Py$ and hence $x=Py\in S$. But why does $y_n$ even converge? This is where I got stuck on.

Comment: $y_n$ does not have to converge. But remember than $P$ is an idempotent.

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I missed that...